# jquery - get array of elements with identical data attribute values

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Given that I have a document similar to this:

```
<div>
    <div data-myAttr = "foo"></div>
    <div data-myAttr = "bar"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div data-myAttr = "foo"></div>
    <div data-myAttr = "bar"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get all elements that contain data-myAttr with foo's and bar's grouped?

Edit: this is more of a theoretical question. I have no tried code that has failed but am exploring a more elegant option for code that already exists.

BTW, thank you for the -1!?

Edit: can someone mark this as duplicate? Found applicable answer here: [Group and count HTML elements by data attribute in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314872/group-and-count-html-elements-by-data-attribute-in-jquery)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried that did not work.

Comment: For exploring more elegant options to already working code, consider http://codereview.stackoverflow.com , and you'll still want to post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is my first ever answer on here so don't judge to harshly... In my case I had duplicates in my array as well.  And I am only just starting to fully understand how this all works but here goes:

```
elements = $('div[data-myAttr]').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-myAttr');
});
```

Then run a basic js loop by name to grab all elements with the correct attr.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and combine two attribute selectors with `comma`;

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxQzW/)**

```
$('[data-myAttr=foo], [data-myAttr=bar]')
```

You can iterate through the elements using `each()`

```
$('[data-myAttr=foo], [data-myAttr=bar]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, is it possible to do this without having to define the data-myAttr value?

Comment: Sorry, I meant without having to define it as part of the selector. Thank you, though!

Comment: Can you explain "without having to define it as part of the selector"?